# mySQL window function with COUNT(DISTINCT)

Tags: mysql

I want to write in MySQL a window function which gives a 30 day roll, counting unique id's. To be more precise, my database has many entries per day as a timestamp, for many different id's. I want to count each day how many different id's connect, and also to get each day the total number of id's that have been online in the last 30 days.

Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_database` (
  `timestamp` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_database (timestamp,id) VALUES (CURDATE(),1);
INSERT INTO my_database (timestamp,id) VALUES (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY),2);
INSERT INTO my_database (timestamp,id) VALUES (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY),1);
INSERT INTO my_database (timestamp,id) VALUES (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY),3);
INSERT INTO my_database (timestamp,id) VALUES (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 29 DAY),4);
INSERT INTO my_database (timestamp,id) VALUES (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 300 DAY),2);
INSERT INTO my_database (timestamp,id) VALUES (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1000 DAY),5);
```

Which looks like:

```
timestamp id
20190730    1
20190729    2
20190728    1
20190728    3
20190701    4
20181003    2
20161102    5
```

The result I want to get is the following:

```
date              count_day     count_30day

2019-07-30            1               4
2019-07-29            1               4
2019-07-28            2               3
2019-07-01            1               1
2018-10-03            1               1
2016-11-02            1               1
```

I don't know how to get the count_30day column. So far I have written the following:

```
SELECT DATE(a.`timestamp`) AS 'date',
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) AS 'count_day',
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) OVER (ORDER BY DATE(a.`timestamp`) ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS 'count_30day'
  FROM my_database AS a
 GROUP 
    BY DATE(a.`timestamp`)
 ORDER 
    BY DATE(a.`timestamp`) DESC
```

However that does not work for the count_30day column. I have been looking at other questions and the documentation and the syntax for the window functions seems to be correct as far as I have seen, but clearly is not as this does not work. How should I write the window function properly? Is there a better way to do this other than COUNT(DISTINCT)? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ROWS PRECEDING` is related to number of rows, doesn't have anything to do with days

You need a subquery:

**[SQL DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f7tWykKWasuzMVKfPJ6PPQ/2)**

```
SELECT DATE(a.`timestamp`) AS 'date',
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) AS 'count_day',
    MAX( (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) 
          FROM my_database db2 
          WHERE db2.timestamp between DATE_SUB(a.timestamp, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
                                  and a.timestamp
          )
       ) as count30
  FROM my_database AS a
 GROUP 
    BY DATE(a.`timestamp`)
 ORDER 
    BY DATE(a.`timestamp`) DESC
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I completely missed that. Thank you!